# How to fix cURL error 35 when consulting endpoints in production server?

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, ssl-certificate

I have a Laravel project consulting various endpoints via get method, and sometimes in random moment return this error:

```
production.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 35: OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to "{service name}"
```

This only occur in production, in dev server and locally is not doing that. The specificactions of productions server are:

```
MariaDB 10.5.15 Ubuntu 21.10 Laravel version 8.54 Library Guzzle 7.0.1 Nginx 1.18.0 The consult look like this: $response = Http::withHeaders($this->headers)->get($query); $response->throw();
```

I think maybe an Nginx config or SSL certificate problem on the server, I tried to update the guzzle library and it keeps giving the same error, I also tested on the development server and no error occurred.

Also doing `nginx -t` result this:

```
nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem" nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I think that SSL certificate is a self-signed, but locally is also a self-signed certificate.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. See [ask]